# Lots of unexplained Careers invitations?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I got an invite to create a SO Careers 2.0 profile a few weeks ago. After getting to over 150 completeness, I received a batch of invites (I think it was 5, but I can't remember).

About a week later, I received an additional 15 invites, along with an explanatory email that stated they were due to my open source involvement. OK, cool.

But, it seems that each week or so I'm getting more invitations, and I have no idea why (no explanatory emails). I remember getting a batch of 14, and then some more, and today I got yet another batch, this time of 12 invites (am I getting one less each week?).

So, why am I getting all these invites? I'm currently at 59 and all I've done is fill out my profile!

**UPDATE:** Just realized that invitations show up in my inbox notifications, and are hence trackable. Here's the timeline:

Jan 11: 5
Jan 12: 5
Jan 18: 15
Jan 25: 14
Feb 1:  13
Feb 8:  12

Seems like it's every week since the batch of 15.

Comment: We just really want you to invite some people! ...but seriously, we're looking into this

Comment: @David: ;-) Thanks. I updated my answer with the dates and invitation counts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for the report.  The cause was that when calculating the number of invites to give you in your next grant we were deducting the *number of times we'd granted you invites* instead of the *quantity of invites we'd granted you*. So you got 15 the first time, then we deducted 1 and gave you 14, then we deducted 2 and gave you 13 etc etc.  We should've stopped after the first grant.

And we've been doing that for 5 months.  So \o/ YAY \o/.

This is fixed in the next push.

Enjoy the extra invites, though!

Comment: Excellent, thought it might be something like that! 5 months though... that just made my day :D

Comment: Wait a second, if you were deducting the number of times you'd given out invites, then wouldn't the sequence be 15, 14, 12, 9, ...? Why was there a consistent base of 15 invites?

Comment: The base comes from the number of followers you have on your open source projects...

Comment: *Oh*, cool, I didn't realize the quantity of invites was based on that!

Comment: @Cameron: It's one of the things we grant invites for.